# How do I update the current animated line graph every time I draw a new one?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, graph

I've been new to python, and recently I am trying with the FuncAnimation recently. I was trying to make a graph that shows the diffusion graphs for every **different p and q values**, so each time it's supposed to **mutate on the current line graph with different p and q as parameters for a fixed amount of t**. I've been trying to animate this so that the change with respect to p and q changes on the graph can be seen.

```
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import math
from IPython import display

def eq(p,q,t):
    return (1-pow(math.e,-(p+q)*t))/(1+q/p*pow(math.e,-(p+q)*t))
def diffusion(p,q,t):
    d=[]
    for i in range(len(t)):
        d.append(eq(p,q,t[i]))
    return np.array(d)

t=np.linspace(0,20,200)

pq=[]
for i in np.linspace(1,0,20,endpoint=False)[::-11]:
    for j in np.linspace(1,0,20,endpoint=False)[::-11]:
        pq.append((i,j))

titles = ["Base Diffusion graph (p={}, q={})".format(round(frame[0],2),round(frame[1],2)) for frame in pq]
#print(titles)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("F(t)")

def buildmechart(i=int):
    plt.title(titles[i])
    p = plt.plot(t,diffusion(pq[i][0],pq[i][1],t)) #note it only returns
    return p,

animator=ani.FuncAnimation(fig,buildmechart,frames=range(len(pq)),interval=100,repeat=False)
animator.save(r'animation.gif')
```

However, when I run the code above there isn't any animated graph saved, instead on jupyter it only shows a static graph of multiple lines on it. This isn't what I intended; I wanted to **change on the current line instead of drawing a new line for each p, q values**. So how should I change this code?

Secondly, when I tried to add blit into the FuncAnimation as a parameter, it doesn't seem to allow me add that due to a error

> RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects.
> So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `func` argument should be a callable that updates the plot. Currently you plot a new line in your update function. There are some simple examples with good explanation on [this page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html) showing how to use the animation feature. Below I slightly modify a few lines of your code to get your desired output.

```py
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import math

def eq(p,q,t):
    return (1-pow(math.e,-(p+q)*t))/(1+q/p*pow(math.e,-(p+q)*t))
def diffusion(p,q,t):
    d=[]
    for i in range(len(t)):
        d.append(eq(p,q,t[i]))
    return np.array(d)

t=np.linspace(0,20,200)

pq=[]
for i in np.linspace(1,0,20,endpoint=False)[::-11]:
    for j in np.linspace(1,0,20,endpoint=False)[::-11]:
        pq.append((i,j))

titles = ["Base Diffusion graph (p={}, q={})".format(round(frame[0],2),round(frame[1],2)) for frame in pq]
#print(titles)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("F(t)")
p, = plt.plot(t,diffusion(pq[0][0],pq[0][1],t))  # Create the line
plt.ylim(-0.05, 1.05)  # Making sure the plot fits

def buildmechart(i=int):
    plt.title(titles[i])
    p.set_data(t,diffusion(pq[i][0],pq[i][1],t))  # Update the line
    return p,

animator=ani.FuncAnimation(fig,buildmechart,frames=range(len(pq)),interval=100,repeat=False)
animator.save(r'animation.gif')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! The blit doesn't show up the error message now, but the animation still doesn't work. Instead, when I try to plot the animation (by using `plt.show()` ) it just shows the box without any sort of line plotted in it. I wonder what is wrong with the animation...?

Comment: Just edited the comment a bit to show your entire code, including also `plt.show()`. If you run this you should get a gif saved under the name `animation.gif` and a window showing the animation once. If you'd like to see it continuously in your plot, then set the argument `repeat` to `True`.